# Move points with same name and the nearest distance

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, move

In QGIS 3.28.3 and i have layers A and B (both contain only points) and I want to move the points in layer B to the nearest point in layer A, under the following conditions:

- The points must have the same name and the nearest distance
- The range should be 10 km only
- That the other points that do not match remain the same

Ex:
[image]
[image]

I tried "Snap Vertices to Nearest Points by Condition"
and "Join attributes by nearest with condition"
From ProcessX but I don't know the correct way to use it, do you have solutions for this problem?

Comment: Have a look at overlay nearest. The crux is grabbing the geometry info from the nearest point with the same value in order to change the geometry of the current feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, *Snap Vertices to Nearest Points by Condition* should actually do just that.

Set it up the following:

- Source Layer: layerB
- Points Layer: layerA
- Snap Vertices: Simply choose all options
- Snap to one and the same point more than once: Use a point as often as it is the nearest match
- Maximum snapping distance: 10000
- Compare-Expression for Source-Layer: your name field of layerB
- Comparison operator: =
- Compare-Expression for Points-Layer: your name field of layerA

Make sure your Source Layer is in a metric CRS. Then run it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried that and it worked for me